# Why are my ASP.NET and html file producing different outputs even though they have similar code and the exact same CSS?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET project with 3 of my friends where we're building a recipe site.

My friends were in charge of doing the frontend and for accidentally created html files as frontends instead of webforms (`.aspx` files). Now I'm trying to convert these html files to ASP.NET.

I've done this by copying and pasting the content of the html file to the asp.net and changing any necessary widgets from html to asp such as `<img>` to `<asp:Image>`, etc.

My only problem is that the CSS works differently for both. For HTML, its perfect, but for the `.aspx` file, it displays the page in a very awkward manner. Here's an example page to showcase the scenario.

**Payment_Complete.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Payment Complete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Payment_Complete.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background-image"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="tick2.png" />
        <h1>Payment Completed!</h1>
        <p>You're now a premium member!</p>
        <p>Ready to dive in for more recipe?&nbsp;<a href="url">Click Here</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Payment_Complete.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Payment_Complete.aspx.cs" Inherits="RecipeHub.Payment_Complete_Page.Payment_Complete" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Payment Complete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Payment_Complete.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <div class="background-image"></div>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="tick2.png" />
        <h1>Payment Completed!</h1>
        <p>You're now a premium member!</p>
        <p>Ready to dive in for more recipe?&nbsp;<a href="url">Click Here</a></p>
    </div></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Payment_Complete.CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}

.background-image {
    background-image: url("background-image.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 50px 80px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

**Here's the html output**

[html output for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsRg0.jpg)

**Here's the aspx output**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqNLM.png)

I've read something about the rending engines being different but can't seem to actually use this information to solve my issue.

Any help or opinion is deeply appreciated. Thank you!

I've read something about the rending engines being different but can't seem to actually use this information to solve my issue.

Comment: The problem is probably `<form id="form1" runat="server">` in the aspx one. Try what happens if you remove it. But maybe this works: `html, body, form { height: 100%; ...`

Comment: Hard to tell - I suspect that bootstrap may well be active here, and it might be adding margins to the form tag. I would hit f12, and inspect the div settings you see for style - this should/would allow tweaking of the css sheet being used. I don't think the existing markup is the issue - but that of additional divs or formatting that is contained in your bootstrap file(s).